# Can the web access depth cameras today by getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediastream

When I enumerate the devices, I see 2 rear cameras out of three for my case (Stylo 6). The third one that is missing I believe is the depth camera. I think it's an actual camera right? Could see visual info... I'm not sure if perhaps it's not useful to be seen visually/just for getting ToF data.

I'm wondering if I should expect this across other devices as well eg. Samsung.

My test code is pretty much boiler plate.

```
...
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(function(devices) {
        devices.forEach(function(device) {
          if (device.kind.indexOf("video") !== -1) {
            detectedCameras += 1;

            if (detectedCameras === 1) {
              ui.innerHTML = "<h2>Choose a camera below</h2>";
            }

            ui.innerHTML += `<button id="${device.deviceId}" class="cam-btn" type="button">${device.label}</button>`;
          }
        });
      })
...
```

I have more code to stop the stream/switch cameras and all that stuff works. But yeah, I can show front/macro/normal but the depth one seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the depth cam in .enumerateDevices(), you won't be able to get to it with .getUserMedia(). Sad but true.

Intel makes a desktop cam with depth that does show up in the enumeration.